# Converting a String object to TEXT object in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

How do I convert a String object to a Text object in hadoop without using a constructor?
There is a Text to String method available, but I couldn't find a String to Text method.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

```
Text text = new Text("your-string");
```

or

```
Text text = new Text();
text.set("your-string");
```

Answer (score 0):

Text class constructor has this provision. [Click here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html#Text%28java.lang.String%29).

OR

You can use [Text.set(String)](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html#set%28java.lang.String%29) method..

Comment: But he is not interested in setting the String using constructor. :-(